# Writing a Customized View - Sencha touch

Tags: html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I need to model the following Screen in `Sencha Touch Architect`;

[image]

Image on the top-left hand side. And on the top-right hand side there is a text (`Custom Tailored Clothing`) and a button beneath it. How can i write the HTML for this?

My working so far;

```
<img src="{url}" height="50" width="50"/>
<b>Custom Tailored Clothing</b>
```

However, the text `Custom Tailored Clothing` appears beneath the image and not on the side as i want it to. Same problem i have with the button. Can someone help me out with the HTML.

UPDATE

Not clear with the parameters: `dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts`

```
onNewsItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {

    if (senchaEvent.event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {

        var form = Ext.create("MyApp.view.DV",{
            title:record.data.Name_mine,
            record:record
        });
        this.getMainView().push(form);
    } else {
        console.log("dfdfd");
    }
},...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
<img src="{url}" height="50" width="50"/>
<div class="title"> <p><b> Custom Tailored Clothing </b></p>
<button>300 mercer st</button></div>
</div>
<p>Why you might like this deal</p>
```

**CSS**

```
div.content {
    height : 50px;
    margin-bottom : 5px;
}
div.content img {
    float : left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**Based on comment**

Add listener in the list

```
listeners : {
        itemtap: function (list, index, item, record, senchaEvent) {
            if (senchaEvent.event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
                // code for getting a message box popped out
            }
            else
              // code for slides to a new view 
        }
}
```

**Update**

```
onNewsItemTap: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {

    if (e.event.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {

        var form = Ext.create("MyApp.view.DV",{
            title:record.data.Name_mine,
            record:record
        });
        this.getMainView().push(form);
    } else {
        console.log("new view");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. But, i have added this to a list view. When i tap on the list view the page slides to another view. Now, when i tap on the button on the listview the page slides to a new view (as before). How can i prevent this?

Comment: I want to get a message box popped out. And, the list should not slide to a new view.

Comment: @sharon Hwk.. see i updated answer.. thats what you need to do

Comment: Give me a minute. i am checking

Comment: That doesn't work. May be because i am using MVC. The list tap event is in the controller. I have added that code above.

Comment: @sharon Hwk.. No that is not the problem.. see i updated answer

Comment: So `e` is `SenchaEvents` ?

Comment: @sharon Hwk.. ya i gave a name 'SenchaEvents' for e.. e is not mean anything.. so  when you read SenchaEvents you will understand that is  an event .. thats why i gave name for e (Event)

Comment: Ok. happy that you got it.

Comment: I think now i answered this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598870/customizing-html-for-the-list-view-cell